# regexp to match xxx.xxx.xxx?

Tags: php, regex

I need to check input with preg_match, which must be of this format: xxx.xxx.xxx
The number of block can vary... These are all examples of valid inputs:

```
001
00a.00a
0fg.001
aaa.aaa.001
001.001.002.001.001.001
```

Well I could probably write a regexp something like:

```
^([\da-z]{3}\.?)+$
```

But here comes the problem with the quantifier of the period. I mean if I use '?' to match 0 or 1 times, it would also match even if skip the dots somewhere, eg:

```
000.001.0010az001
```

then, if I used {1} to match one time, it would match nothing, because the last block does not have a dot.

So I can't think what to think of... Please advice

Comment: Don't you need a backslash in front of the dot to escape it? i.e: `^([\da-z]{3}\.?)+$`

Comment: Yep, I mistyped, already edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^(?:[\da-z]{3}\.)*[\da-z]{3}$/
```

Comment: Thanks for quick replies all! but I just wonder why would we need '?:', wound't it work without it?...

Comment: Yes, that's just a [non-matching group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group).

Comment: Hmmm, I'm confused... Could you just give me some hint about it? ;P

Comment: Oh, thanks, thats a huge one, gotta study it then. :)
I shall accept as the answer then because you actually explained it. I shall also upvote the answer of codaddict ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
^[\da-z]{3}(?:\.[\da-z]{3})*$
```